# A small syntactic problem in javascript- Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, html

this is part of code in javascript for a Tic Tac Toe game. this part is checking win for diagonal in both directions. The diagonals work in X's winning but they do not work in O's winning. I basically wrote the same thing so I'm not sure what's the mistake I made.
Did I make some syntactic mistake?

```
 function CheckWin_Diagonal(rowClicked, colClicked) {
        if (rowClicked == colClicked) {
            for (c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
                if (intBoard[c][c] != X_CLASS)
                    break;
                if (c == rows - 1) {
                    alert("PLAYER X WIN!!");
                    document.location.reload()
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (rowClicked == colClicked) {
                for (c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
                    if (intBoard[c][c] != CIRCLE_CLASS)
                        break;
                    if (c == rows - 1) {
                        alert("PLAYER O WIN!!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    function CheckWin_Diagonal2(rowClicked, colClicked) {
        if (rowClicked + colClicked == cols - 1) {
            for (r = 0; r < cols; r++) {
                if (intBoard[r][(cols - 1) - r] != X_CLASS) 
                    break;
                
                if (r == cols - 1) {
                    alert("PLAYER X WIN!!");
                    document.location.reload()
                  
                }
            }
            
        }
        else {
            if (rowClicked + colClicked == cols - 1) { 
                for (r = 0; r < cols; r++) {
                    if (intBoard[r][(cols - 1) - r] != CIRCLE_CLASS)
                        break;
                    if (r == cols - 1) {
                        alert("PLAYER O WIN!!");
                    }
                }
    
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code that defines all the undefined variables in your code.

Comment: I wouldn't jump to the conclusion that you've made a *syntax error* unless you're actually seeing a *syntax error* in your browser's development console.  Are you?  If you're not seeing any error at all in the console then now is a good time to start [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) to step through the code as it executes, observe the runtime values of the variables, and identify the specific operation which is producing an unexpected result.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the logic at all, but you are doing:

```js
function CheckWin_Diagonal(rowClicked, colClicked) {
        if (rowClicked == colClicked) {
           /** logic **/
        }
        else {
            if (rowClicked == colClicked) {
                /** logic **/
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously the code in the second `if` will never execute because it's the same condition as the first one (so it'll never get there).

You are basically saying:

`IF SOMETHING HAPPENED DO THIS, OTHERWISE IF THE SAME THING HAPPENED DO THAT`

So `THAT` will never happen, because you trapped the condition in the first `IF` and there's no `OTHERWISE` for the exact same condition

Comment: Thanks, this is the first code I write so I do not understand exactly how it works.
So how can I creat a circle win without opening a new function? is there any simple way?

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of explicitly checking whether a given square is an X, check whether the squares all have the same value. If they do, then whatever that value is wins. And if that's unworkable somehow, pass in a third argument that indicates whether you're checking X or O.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` blocks run the same `if` condition that triggered the `else` in the first place, guaranteeing they'll never run.